# Enabling CSPROJ XML Documentation File with Powershell in nuget package

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm working on a nuget package to help standardize some ASP.NET Web API projects. Part of what the nuget package should do is enable XML documentation if it is disabled, so XML comments from the controllers can be used in the help area. I've created the powershell script below for the Install.ps1 in my nuget package, but it doesn't seem to actually change the csproj file. I'm installing the package into a brand new Web API project with the XML documentation file disabled, and it's not working the way I expected. I do know that it is running because I had some other errors that had to be fixed, but now I'm getting no errors or feedback to suggest what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated because it seems pretty tough to debug this the way it gets called in visual studio when installing the nuget package.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($project.FullName)
$nsManager =  New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($doc.NameTable)
$nsManager.AddNamespace('tu','http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')

$node = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//tu:PropertyGroup',$nsManager)

$docNode = $node.SelectSingleNode('//tu:DocumentationFile', $nsManager)

if(!$docNode)
{
                # need to add documentation file
                $element = $doc.CreateElement('DocumentationFile')
                $element.InnerText = 'App_Data\MyProject.xml'
                $node.AppendChild($element)
                $doc.Save($project.FullName)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into a similar issue. I never figured out how to make this work with powershell. I was outputting the XmlDocument using Write-Host and could see it was updated, but my *.csproj file never updated on the call to $doc.Save. The more I worked on this, I found out that powershell isn't the right solution in newer versions of nuget anyway. If you're using version >2.5 of nuget, the right answer is to use an msbuild .props file to modify the properties. In my case, I wanted to set the DocumentationFile property, so I created a build sub-directory in the package and added a file named *packageid.props* (replacing packageid with the actual nuget package ID). The content of the file looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DocumentationFile>App_Data\MyProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

With this file included, my csproj file is updated to link to the props file when the nuget package is installed, and the DocumentationFile property gets set successfully.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved your issue and thanks for sharing your answer here. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was just working on this problem and this was my solution. Bare in mind that I was working on a nuget package for a web project, so having the xml file within the bin folder as a default setting made sense instead of having it under bin\Debug or bin\Release or App_Data like in the original question.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# save project first
$project.Save()

$xml = [xml](Get-Content -path $project.FullName)
$default = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup | Where-Object { $_.Condition -eq $null -and $_.ProjectGuid -ne $null }
if($default.DocumentationFile -eq $null) {
    $path = "bin\$($default.AssemblyName).xml"
    $node = $xml.CreateElement('DocumentationFile', $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
    $node.InnerText = $path
    $default.AppendChild($node) | Out-Null

    # Write formatted xml
    $stringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter 
      $xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $stringWriter 
        $xmlWriter.Formatting = “indented” 
        $xmlWriter.Indentation = 2 
        $xml.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter) 
        $xmlWriter.Flush() 
        $stringWriter.Flush() 
        $stringWriter.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath $project.FullName -Encoding utf8 -Force
      $xmlWriter.Dispose()
    $stringWriter.Dispose()
}
```